# Blur event cancels click event in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a search component in `Vue.js`. When you type into the text input, a list of search results is fetched from the server, then displayed in a list beneath the search field. When you click one of the results, the `submit` event fires.

However, now I tried adding a blur event to the text input, which should hide the list of results when the user clicks away from the input. This works fine, except for one crucial situation - clicking on a result no longer fires the `submit` event.

I understand why this is - the `blur` event apparently fires before the `click` event, and hides the results list before the click can be registered on one of the results. My question is, how do I get around this? I need the results list to close when clicking outside the text input, but I obviously also need the `submit` method to function.

Here is the component in full:

```
<template>
    <div class="search basic-search">
        <input type="text" v-model="search_string" v-on:keyup="search" v-on:focus="activate" v-on:blur="inactivate" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search stocks" />
        <div :class="['search-results', active === true ? 'active' : '']">
            <div class="search-result" v-for="result in search_results" v-on:click="submit(result.id)">
                {{ result.name }} ({{ result.ticker }})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                search_string : '',
                search_results : [],
                active : false
            };
        },

        methods : {
            search : function() {
                const axios_data = {
                    _token  : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    str : this.search_string
                };

                axios.post('/stock-search', axios_data).then(response => {

                    if(response.data.success){
                        this.search_results = response.data.stocks;
                        this.active = true;
                    }

                });
            },

            activate : function() {
                if(this.search_string !== '')
                    this.active = true;
            },

            inactivate : function() {
                this.active = false;
            },

            submit : function(stock_id) {
                document.location = "/graphs/" + stock_id;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could delay the hiding of the box until `click` fires

```
inactivate : function() {
   setTimeout( () => this.active = false, 100)
},
```

You may also try to use `mousedown` instead of `click`

```
<div class="search-result" v-for="result in search_results" v-on:mousedown="submit(result.id)">
```

I don't know if the order of the events is determined, but mousedown should be triggered before blur.

Comment: Thanks. But is there no solution without using a timeout?

Comment: I think you can also use v-on:mousedown instead of v-on:click

Comment: Your mousedown answer really saved my bacon. Thanks!

Comment: Noting for posterity (cos I'm bound to end up here again) that Vue's $nextTick was insufficient and using setTimeout as demonstrated here is the best way to ensure that a map click in openlayers would be handled before the Vue blur handling cleaned up my data!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but instead of click I was doing they "enter". So the solution for Vue is:

```
@keydown.enter="selectPreselectedOption"
```

Which triggers before the blur on my input (which also triggers on enter, but keyup)